# Scale bar on QGIS is showing zero

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, scale-bar

I am using the print layout on QGIS 3.10 and I am trying to add a scalebar to my map. The CRS I am using is ESRI:54030 - World_Robinson. The map's scale is on 164176648. When I set the scalebar to kilometers all that shows is 0.  I had this issue before on another project when using ESRI:2163 - US National Atlas Equal Area. I found that switching the map away from the default ESRI:4326 on the main QGIS window caused this same issue and it was resolved when I switched the CRS only on the print layout. However, this isn't working for me this time. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit of [ESRI:54030 - World_Robinson](https://epsg.io/54030) is in degree, same for [ESRI:2163 - US National Atlas Equal Area](https://epsg.io/2163), and [ESRI:4326](https://epsg.io/4326). This means the scale bar will not show a meaningful scale for unprojected data. Here is the WKT of the above EPSG 54030:

```
PROJCS["World_Robinson",
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Robinson"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","54030"]]
```

The scale bar works properly with projected data, in meter or foot, but not in degree as a unit.